# Documents open in browser only when Remote. Open in application fine when in the office

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I'm a SharePoint user, and when I'm in the office with my work laptop, I can click on links on our SharePoint site, and they open in Word or Excel, etc, just fine.  But when I'm Remote (with the same laptop) and login Remote via VPN, when I click on the links, the documents only open in the browser, which means I can't save or modify the document.  I'm assuming it's some setting in my browser, but haven't been able to find anything.  Thanks for any help  (Using IE8 on Windows 7).

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint works best with Microsoft Windows and Internet Explorer (IE). IE 8 and 9 offer the best experience, whereas IE 10 and 11 may have compatibility issues with SharePoint (sometimes these can be resolved by enabling Compatibility View in the browser).

You may need to add URLs to your Internet Options under the Trusted Sites settings. To do this, you need to:

- Open Internet Explorer.
- Click on the Gear icon in the top right corner and select Internet Options.
- On the Security tab, select the Local Intranet icon and click the Sites button.
- Click Advanced, then enter SharePoint site URL and click Add.
- Click Close, OK and OK again to close all the windows.

Also try downloading the document and then open it in Office Client.